# Linear independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck in an argument. Is the following true:

Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ and $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$ be sets of linear independent vectors. Set $u:=\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i u_i$, for some $\alpha_i$. Now if $u$ is in the linear span of $v_1,\ldots, v_k$ does that imply that all of  $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$ in the span of  ${v_1,\ldots,v_k}$?

Comment: No.  Suppose $\alpha_1=1$ but  $\alpha_i=0$ for $i>1$.  Then we know that $u_1$ is in the span of the $v$'s but that's it.

Comment: To emphasize: it won't help to require that the $\alpha_i$ are non-zero.  Let $u_1=(1,0)$ , $u_2=(0,1)$, and $v=(1,1)$. Then $u_1+u_2$ is in the span of $v$ but neither $u_1$ nor $u_2$ is.